# delimiter in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to capture the elements of a string by splitting it using a delimiterusing a shell script,but I am not able to capture the elements properly if the string has any space among the words between the delimiters

eg:

```
`var=hello;my name is;john
IFS=';' read -ra data<<< "$var"
a=${data[0]}
b=${data[2]}
c=${data[4]}
echo $a
echo $b
echo $c`
```

while am able to capture "hello" in 'a' but "my name is " is not being captured in 'b',am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Your assignment is a syntax error.  You need quotes around `var='hello;my name is;john'`.  With that, `echo "${data[1]}"` (not `[2]`, why do you use that?) produces `my name is`  like you'd expect.  Voting to close as typo / trivial.

Comment: yes I missed to add quotes here,but if  my string doesnt have any spaces it working fine

Comment: Then your shell isn't Bourne-compatible.  In `sh` and compatible implentations like `bash`, an unquoted, unescaped semicolon acts as a statement separator.  `var=moo;bar` results in `var` being set to `moo` and `bar` to be executed as a command.